# How did the ram get up there?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Suddenly, I found my huntsdwarf's ram on the wall. There has never been any ramp or stairs up there, so how could it have happened?

I'm in an Untamed Wilds biome, and have seen flying (non-aggressive) wild animals. Could any of them have put the ram up there?

[image]

Comment: I think there is a thread in the official forums especially discussing such...uhh..."happenings". Though, could be hidden in another thread. Long story short, finding Dwarfs, Dogs and Clothes on the walls has happened before.

Comment: Good to hear, I was afraid I was going to have wild animals picking up my pets and putting them everywhere.

Comment: Well, noone could provide a good explanation, either. [First evidence, only first post](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=82852.0). [And here's a thread about it](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=79499.0).

Comment: May I congratulate you on a pretty good entry in the 'weird title' competition, which has been rather slack recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In combat, it's possible to dodge *up* a Z-level onto the top of an adjacent wall, without any kind of stairway or ramp.  Hysterical strength, I guess.  It's a little-known phenomenon because the circumstances for it are pretty rare.  That's probably what happened to your ram.

Comment: The ram dodged something? ... Oh wait....we're talking about the animal?

Comment: @Bobby: Yes, Toady has not implemented battering rams as yet. :)

Comment: @chaos I guess you could consider trolls to be the current battering rams :D

Comment: So, if you can't ram it, dodge it?